# Passing variable from fancybox to parent page when closing fancybox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

Hi im trying to send a variable from a child iframe fancybox to the parent. But i cant seem to grasp how to do it. Does anyone have a idea. I already tried with js. A friend suggested to do it with php but havent find a solution. I have a mess right now. I tried another questions answers similar to mine with no luck. Here is the code 
this is in the fancybox:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClickButton (nombre) {

        parent.$.nombre(nombre);
        parent.$.fancybox.close();

    }
</script>

<?php foreach($files1 as $file): ?>
                <?php if ($cont>1) { ?>
                  <li>

                        <a onclick="OnClickButton ('<?php echo $file;?>');" href="<?php echo $file;?>"><img style="width: 50px;" 
                            src="img/folderImg.png"></a>

                  </li>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php $cont++; endforeach ?>
```

This is in the parent page

```
function nombre (nombre) {

        name = nombre;
        alert(nombre)

    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 400,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterClose  :   function() {

            if (name == 'folder 1') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }
            if (name == 'folder 2') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb2').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }
            if (name == 'folder 3') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb3').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }

        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: What is the idea: to trigger a thumbnail (in the parent page) that opens fancybox? .... are you using different fancybox scripts for each thumbnail? show the html of the parent page

Comment: it's a bit confusing you need from a page open a fancybox and pass to it some variable?

Comment: I need to pass a variable from the iframe fancybox to the parent page to open a galery fancybox. for some reason this is returning me Folder 1) With all and the ). I am using diferent fancybox scripts for each fancybox.

Comment: you could use a single script for all your fancybox needs though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try two solution, i don't know if in your case can works but are pretty solid.

1) sessionstorage:

using sessionstorage with jquery you can save a parameter and use it later in any page.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("nameofthestorage", yourvalue);
```

and to take the saved info

```
var x = sessionStorage.getItem("nameofthestorage");
```

2)save a php session:

i'm a bit rusted with php but you can see this official and easy guide
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Thank you so much XD that was exactly what I was looking for! :D Thanks!! :D  I would upvote but I cant hehe but Ill mark yours as the answer

Comment: @Jfeuchter: Worth to mention " check what is your target audience and browser support before using this method http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage ... and don't forget to set HTML5 `DOCTYPE`