# Fancybox: afterClose behavior depending on the ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, response, fancybox-2

I'm using an iframed fancybox which has a submit button.

The submit event within the fancybox is managed by ajax.

What I would like is, according to the ajax response (which is an id found in mysql), to have the "afterClose" method to open a specific url.

here is the event on the submit button inside the fancybox:

```
$('.submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
       url: 'ajax.php',
       data: {title:'xxx'},
       type: 'post',
       success: function(response){javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();}
    });
});
```

And here is what I would like within the the fancy box parameters:

```
$(".myfancybox").fancybox({
    ...,
    afterClose:function () {Go to www.whatever.com/index.php?id=ajax_response }
});
```

So, how can I transmit the ajax response to the afterClose method?

Thank you.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23018194/1055987 if that helps or the answers from this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23682336/1055987

Comment: sessionStorage worked, thanks!